# Dúvida com retorno de hora formatada asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server

Na aplicação eu tenho uma consulta que compara a hora atual do servidor com um horário pré - estabelecido gravado em uma tabela:

```sql
select  CAST(HORA_FECHAMENTO AS datetime) as HORA_FECHAMENTO, 
 CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),8) as datetime) as HORA_ATUAL 
 from TB_ESTRACAO  
 where IDEXTRACAO = 1
```

Quando eu envio está informação para a tela eu estou formatando da seguinte forma:

```c#
Session["hora_atual_servidor"] = String.Format("{0:T}", retornoHoraAtual.HORA_ATUAL);
Session["hora_final_valida"] = String.Format("{0:T}", retornoHoraAtual.HORA_FECHAMENTO);
```

A aplicação rodando na máquina local me apresenta a informação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No servidor, a informação e visualiza desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para completar o servidor me retorna o horário errado com uma diferença de praticamente 40 minutos a menos que a hora atual é quando é 22:00 mostra como 10:00 PM, como eu poderia resolver este problema?

Comment: A hospedagem é da vbmahospedagem, o melhor preço é o pior suporte da internet, com toda franqueza.

Comment: Bem, já que nao pode trocar de servidor... já tentou pegar a  HORA ATUAL do SERVIDOR ISS e nao do SQL?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa, eu vou mudar de servidor, porque este esta complicado de trabalhar, mais e quanto a formatação da data, sabe o porque?

Comment: Pode ser que na sua máquina esteja configurado PT-BR e no servidor que está usando é Americano (Americano é mais comum)... Tem um lugar que da para alterar no SQL.

Comment: sim, no servidor esta em inglês, como eu tenho a data de fechamento cadastrada, eu uso o horário  assim 20:00 é não 08:00 PM, teria como fazer esta formatação?

Comment: Sim, voce pode fazer do lado do servidor... no C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este problema se dá por causa do Globalization, você tem duas opções para resolver isto, alterar a CultureInfo que a sua aplicação está rodando, daí ele alterará para todas as chamadas, ou seja, você deve perceber que o separador de milhar é ',' e o separador decimal é '.', pois a cultura deve estar rodando em Inglês.

Para alterar para toda a aplicação, você pode alterar no web.config, conforme link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkak5b9(v=vs.71).aspx

Ou alterar somente na formatação deste retorno, conforme linha abaixo:

```
 string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:T}", DateTime.Now)
```

Sobre a diferença de 40 minutos se dá por que o servidor onde está o seu banco de dados deve estar em outra TimeZone.

Você pode recuperar a hora local com base em Brasília, desta forma:

```
Session["hora_atual_servidor"] = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. South America Standard Time")); //"E. South America Standard Time" é Brasília
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito grato pela ajuda!